# Why am I getting an undefined reference error while using separate .cpp and .h files for a class?

Tags: c++

I am using a simple function to add to integers, the class is declared in the Adder.h file as below

```
class Adder
{
    public:
    int add (int x, int y);
};
```

Then I have the Adder.cpp file which has the function definition

```
int add (int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Then the main.cpp file which calls the function

```
# include "Adder.h"
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Adder adder1;
    int result = adder1.add (2, 3);
    cout << result;
}
```

I ran g++ -c Adder.cpp to create Adder.o file beforehand.
Then I ran g++ main.cpp but go the following error

main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `Adder::add(int, int)'

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358745/how-to-use-libraries)

Comment: You haven't passed in "Adder.o" when compiling the program with "main.cpp".

Comment: You define a free function in .cpp, You do not implement the class method.

Comment: @Maaz Although the other answers were much more concise but the link you shared was very informative. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second and final step, you didn't instruct the compiler (linker more exactly) to take into account `Adder.o`, so your final executable still doesn't know the implementation of `Adder::add`
Try, after getting Adder.o, to run `g++ main.cpp Adder.o`

Also, this may be relevant : [Difference between compiling with object and source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437275/difference-between-compiling-with-object-and-source-files)

Also, if that is the complete code, as others have pointed out, in the `Adder.cpp`, you are just defining a simple function, not the one from the `Adder` class.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you've defined a **free function** named `add` instead of defining a member function of class `Adder`. To define `add` as a member function we have to be in the *scope of the class* `Adder` which we can do by adding `Adder::` before `add` as shown below:

**Adder.cpp**

```
//note the use of scope resolution operator ::
int Adder::add(int x, int y)//define a member function instead of a free function
{
    return x + y;
}
```

In the above modified code, we are defining the member function `add` instead of the free function `add`.